# AWS Session Manager Exception for ListAssociation

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-session-manager

Encountered below error while doing health check for session manager on AWS:

```
amazon-ssm-agent[17614]: 2020-05-19 12:57:35 ERROR [MessagingDeliveryService] [Association] Unable to load instance associations, unable to retrieve associations unable to retrieve associations AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::395456465418:assumed-role/SessionManagerInstanceProfile/i-02c8c2ae1dce2ce84 is not authorized to perform: ssm:ListAssociations on resource: arn:aws:ssm:ap-southeast-1:395456465418:*
```

Believe this is caused by insufficient privilege granted for the instance IAM policy. But what additional access should I grant in order to resolve this error?

Below is the current inline policy which was copied from AWS documentation.

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "ssmmessages:CreateControlChannel",
            "ssmmessages:CreateDataChannel",
            "ssmmessages:OpenControlChannel",
            "ssmmessages:OpenDataChannel",
            "ssm:UpdateInstanceInformation"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "logs:CreateLogStream",
            "logs:PutLogEvents",
            "logs:DescribeLogGroups",
            "logs:DescribeLogStreams"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::ec2-sessionmanager-logs"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:GetEncryptionConfiguration"
        ],
        "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": "kms:GenerateDataKey",
        "Resource": "*"
    }
]
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicates:

> is not authorized to perform: **ssm:ListAssociations**

The action:

> Grants permission to list the associations for a specified SSM document or managed instance

Thus, the policy should contain: `ssm:ListAssociations`. Currently, in the policy you've posted in the question, there is no such action permitted.